# Android Asynctask Not Work Prorperly is not give data or sometime fail

Tags: android, json, android-asynctask

I am trying load the data using json parsing in asynctask but is not load properly
sometimes not get complete data some times is said android.os.main thread I was tried many times but still I am getting problem 
I puting my code & logcat here

here is my main class

HomeACtivity.java

```
class HomeACtivity extends Activity 
 {
  @Override
     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 {
            new FlightListBack.execute("");
   }
 }


 public class FlightListBack extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>>

{

ArrayList<String> airportList = new ArrayList<String>();
final  JsonParser jparser= new JsonParser();
final  ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> spinnerAirportList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

String airporturl="http://api.flightstats.com/flex/airports/rest/v1/json/withinRadius/-74.0063/40.7141/100?appId=4dde11f5&appKey=6b80a6ed5d82c8f0b28dadb14e81bfcd";
String spinnerstringfunction;


List<String> spinnercityList= new ArrayList<String>();
final List<String> spinnerAirportNameList= new ArrayList<String>();
JSONArray  sjairport;



@Override
protected ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> doInBackground(
        String... params) {

    spinnerstringfunction=jparser.getJSONFromUrl(airporturl);

    Log.e("SpinnerstringFunction", "size"+spinnerstringfunction);

    try
    {
    // Getting Array of Contacts
    JSONObject jobject= new JSONObject(spinnerstringfunction);          //  Log.e("JOBJECT ","ACTIVITY-->"+jobject.length());

    // Airlines Array For Getting Airlines Name
    sjairport=jobject.getJSONArray(TAG_AIRPORT);            //  Log.e("JSONARRAY","AIRLINES"+jairlines.length());



    for(int a=0;a<sjairport.length()-30;a++)
    {

        HashMap<String, String> spinnermap = new HashMap<String, String>();

        String spinnerfs=sjairport.getJSONObject(a).get(TAG_SPINNERFS).toString(); 
        String spinnername=sjairport.getJSONObject(a).get(TAG_SPINNERNAME).toString();
        String  spinnercity=sjairport.getJSONObject(a).get(TAG_SPINNERCITY).toString();

        spinnermap.put(TAG_SPINNERFS, spinnerfs);
        spinnermap.put(TAG_SPINNERNAME,spinnername);
        spinnermap.put(TAG_SPINNERCITY,spinnercity);


        if(!spinnercityList.contains(spinnercity))
        {
            spinnercityList.add(spinnercity);  // spinner city list
        }

        spinnerAirportList.add(spinnermap); // Array List For all hash map list 
    }
    Log.e("Spinner Airport List","Complete"+spinnercityList.size()); //
//  Log.e("Airport List","Complete"+spinnerAirportList); //

    Log.e("Spinner Airport List","Complete"+spinnercityList);

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    return spinnerAirportList;
}


protected void onPostExecute(String...result)
{

    try
    {



    cityspinner=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinnercity);
    namespinner=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinnername);
    timespinner=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinnertime);
    buttontime=(Button)findViewById(R.id.buttontime);

        ArrayAdapter<String> spinneradapter= new ArrayAdapter<String>(HomeActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,spinnercityList);
        spinneradapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        cityspinner.setAdapter(spinneradapter);


        // country spinner onclick start

        cityspinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                    int arg2, long arg3) {

                String cityselected=cityspinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
                Log.e("city, selected", "Work"+cityselected);
                spinnerAirportNameList.clear();
                for(int b=0;b<spinnerAirportList.size();b++)
                {

                    if(cityselected.equals(spinnerAirportList.get(b).get(TAG_SPINNERCITY).toString()))
                    {
                        clear();
                        String airportname=spinnerAirportList.get(b).get(TAG_SPINNERNAME).toString();
                        Log.e("country, selected", "Work"+cityselected);
                        Log.e("country Selected Airport","work"+airportname);
                        spinnerAirportNameList.add(airportname);
                    }
                }
                Log.e("Spinner Airport NAme list","Work"+spinnerAirportNameList);

                ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerairportnameadapter= new ArrayAdapter<String>(HomeActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,spinnerAirportNameList);
                spinnerairportnameadapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                namespinner.setAdapter(spinnerairportnameadapter);

            }

            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {

            }

        });

        // country spinner onclick finish



        // name spinner onclick start

        namespinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                    int arg2, long arg3) {


                String nameselected=namespinner.getSelectedItem().toString();

                Log.e("Name, selected", "Work"+nameselected);

                for(int c=0;c<spinnerAirportList.size();c++)
                {   
                    if(nameselected.equals(spinnerAirportList.get(c).get(TAG_SPINNERNAME).toString()))
                    {
                        spinnerairportfs=spinnerAirportList.get(c).get(TAG_SPINNERFS).toString();
                        Log.e("Name, selected", "Work"+nameselected);
                        Log.e("fs Selected Airport","work"+spinnerairportfs);

                    }
                }

            }
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {

            }
        });



        //name spinner onclick finish

        // time spinner
     String[] flighttime={"12:00AM To 1:00AM"   ,   "1:00AM To 2:00AM"   ,  "2:00AM To 3:00AM",
                          "3:00AM To 4:00AM"    ,   "4:00AM To 5:00AM"   ,  "5:00AM To 6:00AM",
                          "6:00AM To 7:00AM"    ,   "7:00PM To 8:00AM"   ,  "8:00AM To 9:00AM",
                          "9:00AM To 10:00AM"   ,   "10:00PM To 11:00AM" ,  "11:00AM To 12:00PM",
                          "12:00PM To 1:00PM"   ,   "1:00PM To 2:00PM"   ,  "2:00PM To 3:00PM",
                          "3:00PM To 4:00PM"    ,   "4:00PM To 5:00PM"   ,  "5:00PM To 6:00PM",
                          "6:00PM To 7:00PM"    ,   "7:00PM To 8:00PM"   ,  "8:00PM To 9:00PM",
                          "9:00PM To 10:00PM"   ,   "10:00PM To 11:00PM" ,  "11:00PM To 12:00PM"};

        ArrayAdapter<String>spinnertimeadapter= new ArrayAdapter<String>(HomeActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,flighttime);
        spinnertimeadapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        timespinner.setAdapter(spinnertimeadapter);

        timespinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                    int arg2, long arg3) {

                String timeselected=timespinner.getSelectedItem().toString();

                if(timeselected.equals("12:00AM To 1:00AM"))
                {

                    time="0";
                }
                else if(timeselected.equals("1:00AM To 2:00AM"))
                {
                    time="1";
                }
                else if(timeselected.equals("2:00AM To 3:00AM"))
                {
                    time="2";
                }
                else if(timeselected.equals("3:00AM To 4:00AM"))
                {
                    time="3";
                }
                else if(timeselected.equals("4:00AM To 5:00AM"))
                {
                    time="4";
                }
                else if(timeselected.equals("5:00AM To 6:00AM"))
                {
                    time="5";
                }
                else if(timeselected.equals("6:00AM To 7:00AM"))
                {
                    time="6";
                }
                else if(timeselected.equals("7:00AM To 8:00AM"))
                {
                    time="7";
                }
                else if(timeselected.equals("8:00AM To 9:00AM"))
                {
                    time="8";
                }
                else if(timeselected.equals("9:00AM To 10:00AM"))
                {
                    time="9";
                }
                else if(timeselected.equals("10:00AM To 11:00AM"))
                {
                    time="10";
                }
                else if(timeselected.equals("11:00AM To 12:00PM"))
                {
                    time="11";
                }
                else if(timeselected.equals("12:00PM To 1:00PM"))
                {
                    time="12";
                }
                else if(timeselected.equals("1:00PM To 2:00PM"))
                {
                    time="13";
                }
                else if(timeselected.equals("2:00PM To 3:00PM"))
                {
                    time="14";
                }
                else if(timeselected.equals("3:00PM To 4:00PM"))
                {
                    time="15";
                }
                else if(timeselected.equals("4:00PM To 5:00PM"))
                {
                    time="16";
                }
                else if(timeselected.equals("5:00PM To 6:00PM"))
                {
                    time="17";
                }
                else if(timeselected.equals("6:00PM To 7:00PM"))
                {
                    time="18";
                }
                else if(timeselected.equals("7:00PM To 8:00PM"))
                {
                    time="19";
                }
                else if(timeselected.equals("8:00PM To 9:00PM"))
                {
                    time="20";
                }
                else if(timeselected.equals("9:00PM To 10:00PM"))
                {
                    time="21";
                }
                else if(timeselected.equals("10:00PM To 11:00PM"))
                {
                    time="22";
                }
                else if(timeselected.equals("11:00PM To 12:00PM"))
                {
                    time="23";
                }
            }
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {

            }
        });




    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    buttontime.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {


             ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> flightList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();




              Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
              int year = now.get(Calendar.YEAR);
              Log.e("Year","ss"+year);
              int month = now.get(Calendar.MONTH); // Note: zero based!
              Log.e("Month","ss"+month);

              int day = now.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
              Log.e("day","ss"+day);

              Log.e("Time is Selected","time"+time);

                Log.e("Spinner airoort fs","fs"+spinnerairportfs);
                String flighturl = "http://api.flightstats.com/flex/flightstatus/rest/v2/json/airport/status/"+spinnerairportfs+"/dep/"+year+"/"+month+"/"+day+"/"+time+"?appId=4dde11f5&appKey=6b80a6ed5d82c8f0b28dadb14e81bfcd&utc=false&numHours=1";

                Log.e("Flight url","Work"+flighturl);
                String jsonstringfunction=jparser.getJSONFromUrl(flighturl);


                try
                {

                        JSONObject jobject= new JSONObject(jsonstringfunction); 
                        JSONObject appendix = jobject.getJSONObject(TAG_APPENDIX);              Log.e("JOBJECT ","APPENDIX-->"+appendix.length());

                        // Airlines Array For Getting Airlines Name
                        JSONArray  jairlines=appendix.getJSONArray(TAG_AIRLINES);               Log.e("JSONARRAY","AIRLINES"+jairlines.length());

                        // Airport Array For Getting Airport Name
                        JSONArray  jairport=appendix.getJSONArray(TAG_AIRPORT);                 Log.e("JSONARRAY","AIRPORT"+jairport.length());

                        // Flightstatuses Array For Getting INFO
                        JSONArray jflightstatuses=jobject.getJSONArray(TAG_FLIGHTSTATUSES);     Log.e("JSONARRAY","FLIGHTSTATUSES"+jflightstatuses.length());

                        int i;
                        int j;
                        int k;
                        int m;
                        int n;


                        //****************************** Flightstatuses Array *****************************
                        for(i=0;i<jflightstatuses.length();i++)
                        {
                            clear();
                            // creating new HashMap
                            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();


                            arrivalairportfscode=jflightstatuses.getJSONObject(i).get(TAG_ARRIVALAIRPORTFSCODE).toString();     //  Log.e("ArrivalAirportFsCode","AirportFSCode"+arrivalairportfscode);
                            carrierfscode=jflightstatuses.getJSONObject(i).get(TAG_CARRIERFSCODE).toString(); 
                            flightnumber=jflightstatuses.getJSONObject(i).get(TAG_FLIGHTNUMBER).toString();


                            //****************************** Airport Array *****************************
                            // Comparing ArrivalAirportFsCode For Finding The City Name
                            for(j=0;j<jairport.length();j++)
                            {
                                // Airport Fs Code from AirportArray
                                airportfs=jairport.getJSONObject(j).get(TAG_AIRPORTFS).toString(); //   Log.e("AIRPORT","FS"+airportfs);

                                // Compare ArrivalAirport FsCode and Airport Fs Code For Finding City Name
                                if(arrivalairportfscode.equalsIgnoreCase(airportfs))
                                {   
                                    // City Name From Airport Array
                                    city=jairport.getJSONObject(j).get(TAG_AIRPORTCITY).toString();     //Log.e("Airport City","City-->"+city);
                                    destination="( "+arrivalairportfscode+" ) "+city;       //Log.e("Destination City","city"+destination);
                                    flight=carrierfscode+" "+flightnumber;

                                }
                            }   // airport for loop complete

                            map.put(TAG_MDESTINATION, destination);
                            map.put(TAG_MFLIGHT,flight);


                            for(k=0;k<jairlines.length();k++)
                            {

                                // Airport Fs Code from AirportArray
                                airlinesfs=jairlines.getJSONObject(k).get(TAG_AIRLINESFS).toString();   //Log.e("AIRLINES","FS"+airlinesfs);

                                // Compare ArrivalAirport FsCode and Airport Fs Code For Finding City Name
                                if(carrierfscode.equalsIgnoreCase(airlinesfs))
                                {   
                                    // Airlines Name From Airlines Array
                                    airlinesname=jairlines.getJSONObject(k).get(TAG_AIRLINENAME).toString();        //Log.e("AIRLINES NAME","NAME"+airlinesname);
                                    Log.e("--"+flight,"--"+airlinesname);

                                }

                            } // airlines for loop complete
                            map.put(TAG_MAIRLINE,airlinesname);

                            JSONObject joperationaltimes=jflightstatuses.getJSONObject(i).getJSONObject(TAG_OPERATIONALTIMES);
                            Log.e("Operational times","-->"+joperationaltimes);

                            // Schedule Time 

                            JSONObject jschedulegatedeparture =new JSONObject();
                            JSONObject jestimateddeparture =new JSONObject();

                            for(m=0;m<joperationaltimes.length();m++)
                            {   
                                if(joperationaltimes.has(TAG_SCHEDULEDGATEDEPARTURE))
                                {   

                                       jschedulegatedeparture=joperationaltimes.getJSONObject(TAG_SCHEDULEDGATEDEPARTURE);
                                       schedule=jschedulegatedeparture.getString(TAG_SCHEDULEDATELOCAL).toString();
                                       schedule=schedule.substring(11);

                                       Log.e("Before convert","Time"+schedule);

                                       DateFormat f1 = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss");
                                       Date d = f1.parse(schedule);
                                       DateFormat f2 = new SimpleDateFormat("h:mm a");
                                       schedule=f2.format(d).toLowerCase(); // "12:18am"

                                       Log.e("After convert","Time"+schedule);
                                     //  jestimateddeparture=joperationaltimes.getJSONObject(TAG_ACTUALGATEDEPARTURE);
                                     //  actual=jestimateddeparture.getString(TAG_ACTUALDATELOCAL).toString();
                                     //  actual=actual.substring(11);
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                     schedule="Not Available";
                                }

                            }
                            map.put(TAG_MSCHEDULE, schedule);

                            //Log.e("ScheduleGatedtime",""+jschedulegatedeparture);
                            //Log.e("Schedule Time","Work"+schedule);
                            //Log.e("ActualGatedtime",""+jestimateddeparture);
                            //Log.e("Actual Time","Work"+actual);

                            //------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

                            // AIRPORT RESOURCES OBJECT fOR getting departure terminal and departure gate

                            if(jflightstatuses.getJSONObject(i).has(TAG_AIRPORTRESOURCES))
                            {   

                            JSONObject airportresources=jflightstatuses.getJSONObject(i).getJSONObject(TAG_AIRPORTRESOURCES);
                            Log.e("airportresources","--->"+airportresources);

                                if(airportresources.has(TAG_DEPARTURETERMINAL))
                                {
                                    departureterminal=airportresources.get(TAG_DEPARTURETERMINAL).toString();
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    departureterminal=""; 

                                }

                                if(airportresources.has(TAG_DEPARTUREGATE))
                                {
                                    departuregate=airportresources.get(TAG_DEPARTUREGATE).toString();

                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    departuregate="";
                                }
                                terminal="T-"+departureterminal+" ";
                                gate=departuregate;
                                terminalgate=terminal+gate;
                                Log.e("Terminal Gate","-->"+terminal+gate);

                                map.put(TAG_MTERMINALGATE,terminalgate);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                terminalgate="Not Available";
                                map.put(TAG_MTERMINALGATE,terminalgate);
                            }
                            //--------------------------------Aiport Resources Complete---------------------------------------------------


                            //--------------------------------Aiport Flight Status Start--------------------------------------------------- 

                                status=jflightstatuses.getJSONObject(i).getString(TAG_STATUS).toString();
                                if(status.equalsIgnoreCase("S"))
                                {
                                    status="Scheduled";
                                }
                                if(status.equalsIgnoreCase("L"))
                                {
                                    status="Landed";
                                }
                                map.put(TAG_MFSTATUS, status);
                                Log.e("Status","--"+status);
                            //--------------------------------Aiport Flight Status Complete---------------------------------------------------  

                        flightList.add(map);

                        Log.e("FlightList","work"+flightList);

                        int displaymode=getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;
                        if(displaymode==1)
                        {

                                ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(HomeActivity.this, flightList,
                                        R.layout.listportrait,
                                        new String[] { TAG_MDESTINATION, TAG_MFLIGHT, TAG_MAIRLINE,TAG_MSCHEDULE,TAG_MTERMINALGATE,TAG_MFSTATUS  }, new int[] {
                                                R.id.textdestination, R.id.textflight, R.id.textairline,R.id.textschedule,R.id.texttermgate,R.id.textstatus });
                                setListAdapter(adapter);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(HomeActivity.this, flightList,
                                    R.layout.list,
                                    new String[] { TAG_MDESTINATION, TAG_MFLIGHT, TAG_MAIRLINE,TAG_MSCHEDULE,TAG_MTERMINALGATE,TAG_MFSTATUS  }, new int[] {
                                            R.id.textdestination, R.id.textflight, R.id.textairline,R.id.textschedule,R.id.texttermgate,R.id.textstatus });
                            setListAdapter(adapter);

                        }

                        }   




                }           
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

        }
    });

    }


}
```

JsonParser.java

```
public class JsonParser {

    static InputStream is = null;
    //static JSONObject jObj = null;
    static String json;
    StringBuilder sb;



    public String getJSONFromUrl(String url) {



        // Making HTTP request
        try {
            is = null;
            //static JSONObject jObj = null;
            json="";
            sb=null;


            // defaultHttpClient
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            Log.e("HTTPPOST","WORK-->"+httpPost);

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            Log.e("HTTPRESPONSE","WORK-->"+httpResponse);

            StatusLine statusLine=httpResponse.getStatusLine();
            int statusCode= statusLine.getStatusCode();
            Log.e("status", "code"+statusCode);

            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            Log.e("HTTPENTITY","WORK-->"+httpEntity);
            is = httpEntity.getContent();   
        }   
            catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            try{
        //  Log.e("HTTENTITY is","WORK"+is);


            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            Log.e("BUFFER READER","WORK-->"+reader);


            sb = new StringBuilder();
            Log.e("STRINGBUILDER","WORK");

            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line);
            }
            //is.close();
            json = sb.toString();
            Log.e("STRINGBUILDER","WORK"+sb.toString());
        //  Log.e("HTTPPOST SB TO STRING","WORK-->"+sb.toString());
        //  Log.e("JSON STRING HTTPPOST","WORK-->"+json);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }

        // return JSON String
        //return json;

        return sb.toString();

    }


}
```

> Logcat
>   12-08 12:26:57.557: D/AndroidRuntime(1873): Shutting down VM
>   12-08 12:26:57.557: W/dalvikvm(1873): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a5f1f8)
>   12-08 12:26:57.567: E/AndroidRuntime(1873): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   12-08 12:26:57.567: E/AndroidRuntime(1873): android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
>   12-08 12:26:57.567: E/AndroidRuntime(1873):     at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1099)
>   12-08 12:26:57.567: E/AndroidRuntime(1873):     at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:391)
>   12-08 12:26:57.567: E/AndroidRuntime(1873):     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:242)
>   12-08 12:26:57.567: E/AndroidRuntime(1873):     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:220)
>   12-08 12:26:57.567: E/AndroidRuntime(1873):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:137)
>   12-08 12:26:57.567: E/AndroidRuntime(1873):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
>   12-08 12:26:57.567: E/AndroidRuntime(1873):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
>   12-08 12:26:57.567: E/AndroidRuntime(1873):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:360)
>   12-08 12:26:57.567: E/AndroidRuntime(1873):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
>   12-08 12:26:57.567: E/AndroidRuntime(1873):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
>   12-08 12:26:57.567: E/AndroidRuntime(1873):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
>   12-08 12:26:57.567: E/AndroidRuntime(1873):     at com.example.vixxa.JsonParser.getJSONFromUrl(JsonParser.java:96)
>   12-08 12:26:57.567: E/AndroidRuntime(1873):     at com.example.vixxa.HomeActivity$FlightListBack$4.onClick(HomeActivity.java:1815)
>   12-08 12:26:57.567: E/AndroidRuntime(1873):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3511)
>   12-08 12:26:57.567: E/AndroidRuntime(1873):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14109)
>   12-08 12:26:57.567: E/AndroidRuntime(1873):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
>   12-08 12:26:57.567: E/AndroidRuntime(1873):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
>   12-08 12:26:57.567: E/AndroidRuntime(1873):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
>   12-08 12:26:57.567: E/AndroidRuntime(1873):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
>   12-08 12:26:57.567: E/AndroidRuntime(1873):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   12-08 12:26:57.567: E/AndroidRuntime(1873):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>   12-08 12:26:57.567: E/AndroidRuntime(1873):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
>   12-08 12:26:57.567: E/AndroidRuntime(1873):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
>   12-08 12:26:57.567: E/AndroidRuntime(1873):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>   12-08 12:26:58.097: I/dalvikvm(1873): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
>   12-08 12:26:58.107: I/dalvikvm(1873): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
>   12-08 12:31:41.347: I/Process(1873): Sending signal. PID: 1873 SIG: 9

Comment: if you are returning `spinnerAirportList` from doInBackground` then why you are not using it inside `onPostExecute` ? just change `onPostExecute(String...result)` to `onPostExecute(ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> result) `and use `result` for setting datasource for spinner to get better response

Comment: thanks i was change the onpostexecuteto (ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> result> and is work upto this but when i click on buttontime so is gives force to close  and in logcat is gives error 12-08 12:26:57.567: E/AndroidRuntime(1873): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-08 12:26:57.567: E/AndroidRuntime(1873): android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
12-08 12:26:57.567: E/AndroidRuntime(1873):  at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1099)
12-08 12:26:57.567: E/AndroidRuntime(1873):  at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:391)

Comment: ok what you are doing on button click and also post latest logcat when application is crashing on button click

Comment: i will put my logcat on upper side

Comment: log clearly state you are doing network operation on UI Thread . so post more code what u are doing inside button click

Comment: u can see in buttonclick i am getting spinner airport city code from spinner arraylist and when geting the code i m sending other webservice url for get the flighttime list using json parsing for fill LISTVIEW but when i am click on button click is gives error force to close

Comment: what is line:1815 in HomeActivity.java class"

Comment: is my home activity Class i wills send you my complete Homeactivity.java

Comment: this asynctask is i am put down in my home activity class and 1815 error is this line in async task                                   String jsonstringfunction=jparser.getJSONFromUrl(flighturl); this is line

Comment: is my mistake i was show you two different class but asynctask class is in HomeActivity Class

Comment: but you are also calling `String jsonstringfunction=jparser.getJSONFromUrl(flighturl);` on button click so just comment it.

Comment: CAN I USE MULTIPLE ASYNCTASK CLASS IN SINGLE ACTIVITY

Comment: if you are using API LEVEL 9 or greater then from 9 then just put this `StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy); `code inside onCreate of HomeActivity

Comment: you have created your project in  Android 2.3 or greater then  version?

Comment: yes previous error is gone but one more error is occured               12-08 12:57:53.676: W/System.err(1938): org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connection to http://api.flightstats.com refused
12-08 12:57:53.676: W/System.err(1938):  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:183)
12-08 12:57:53.676: W/System.err(1938):  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)

Comment: i  use the Android 4.0.3 for this application

Comment: plz post all new log with your question and make sure you have added Internet permission in androidmanifast.xml

Answer (score 0):

You call JsonParser.getJSONFromUrl from FlightListBack$4.onClick (your anonymous clicklistener you have added here: buttontime.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){..})

In this JsonParser.getJSONFromUrl you perform an http request which then runs on the main thread (or UI thread) because it is started from onClick(). You should restructure your code to perform the http requests on a worker thread (using, for instance, an AsyncTask) just like you did in the other case you call JsonParser.getJSONFromUrl.

Answer (score -1):

add this code in onCreate(); method befor you excute the AsynckTask

```
StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
                 .detectDiskReads()
                 .detectDiskWrites()
                 .detectNetwork()   // or .detectAll() for all detectable problems
                 .penaltyLog()
                 .build());
         StrictMode.setVmPolicy(new StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder()
                 .detectLeakedSqlLiteObjects()
                 .detectLeakedClosableObjects()
                 .penaltyLog()
                 .penaltyDeath()
                 .build());
```

But keep in mind that this code is helpful for development phase, you have to remove it and don't use any network operations in production phase.